# How do I remove an alias?

Tags: command-line, alias

I want to remove `gs` alias from my PC. When I type `gs` it will open GhostScript. But I checked everywhere in the home directory `.alias`  `.bash_aliases` `.bashrc`

I also overwrite the `gs` with my custom alias.

I can't remove it. And I also type `alias` in terminal, in the list I couldn't find it.

Please I want to remove it...

Comment: gs isn't an alias, it's the name of the GhostScript binary. If you want gs to do nothing then you would have to uninstall ghostscript from your system although this probably isn't a good idea as a lot of other software depends on it.

Comment: @Cheesemill and that explains the ?  I had in my head. Why do you assume it is aliased jean000? :)

Comment: You can use `type gs` to check if the command is an executable file, an alias, a bash function or a bash builtin.

Comment: `alias --help`, unhelpfully, does not reveal any useful answer to this question

Comment: Actually `/usr/bin/ghostscript` is a symbolic link to `/usr/bin/gs`. So `file $(which gs)` should show ELF which is your executable file and of course, `file $(which ghostscript)` should show "`symbolic link to gs`".

Comment: Also, `dpkg -L ghostscript` or `dpkg -L ghostscript | grep bin` should show all the files included with the ghostscript package that are (should be) in your $PATH.

Comment: Besides `type gs` command noted above, you may also try `which gs`.

Answer (score 511):

The command to remove an alias is `unalias` so....

```
 unalias gs
```

[Manual](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/unalias.1posix.html):

**NAME**

> unalias - remove alias definitions

**SYNOPSIS**

```
unalias alias-name...

unalias -a
```

**DESCRIPTION**

> The  unalias  utility  shall  remove the definition for each alias name
>          specified. See Alias Substitution . The aliases shall be  removed  from
>          the   current   shell   execution   environment;  see  Shell  Execution
>          Environment .
>
> `-a`   Removes All aliases

Comment: not working I got `unalias: no such hash table element: gs`

Comment: Then you do NOT have it alias'd.

Comment: caution: `unalias -a` will `remove  all  alias  definitions from the current shell execution environment.`, possibly including other innocent ones.

Comment: @assylias I missed that  :) edited

Comment: unalias -a as Huey said removes all inocent ones, for example 'll'. To have it back use 'source ~/.bashrc'

Comment: `unalias` removes an alias or aliases from the current shell, but if they are 'stored' in for example `~/.bashrc`, they will come back when you create a new shell (or terminal window). So you should remove the definition of the aliases from where they are stored in order to get rid of them, unless they are temporary aliases.

Comment: To additional recheck: first try `alias -p` to see all your alias and after that do the proper `unalias`.

Comment: Why do I come here every 3 months?

Comment: FYI: in case you see an error ``syntax error near unexpected token `('`` when sourcing a file, it may be due to having deleted an alias and replaced it with a function. If you do that, you have to do `unalias my_old_alias_name` before you can redefine that name now as a bash function.

Answer (score 9):

TL;DR: The command to remove a shell alias is `unalias`. See the [unalias manual](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/unalias.1posix.html). Run:

```bsh
unalias gs
```

But if your `gs` command is not an alias (most likely), it will not help. The response will be something like:

> bash: unalias: gs: not found

To find the *type* of the command trouble you're in, use `type` built-in shell command:

```bsh
type gs
```

On my system it says it is an executable:

> gs is /usr/bin/gs

Compare that with a common alias `ll`:

```bsh
alias ll='ls -l'
type ll
```

> ll is aliased to `ls -l'

See `help type` for detailed description of the `type` [shell built-in command](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html)

You can also check if it is a symbolic link with:

```bsh
ls -la /usr/bin/gs
```

On my system it isn't:

> -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 14520 Aug 24 17:03 /usr/bin/gs

Otherwise there would be an arrow like this:

> -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 14520 Aug 24 17:03 /usr/bin/gs -> /some/other/file

As pointed out by others, removing the alias from the current shell session is temporary. For permanent removal, you will need to find where it is defined, such as `alias gs=xyz`, and remove it there, or add `unalias gs` to your `~/.profile` or `~/.bashrc` file.

If it is not an alias, you can locate the package that installed the command and uninstall it. On Debian/Ubuntu for instance:

```bsh
dpkg -S /usr/bin/gs
```

> ghostscript: /usr/bin/gs

```bsh
sudo apt-get remove ghostscript
```

Answer (score 4):

If `unalias` is not working, as is currently the case with [fish-shell](https://fishshell.com/) (refer to this issue [#7132](https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/7132) from fish-shell github page for more details), you can use `functions` with `-e` (erase functions) to erase the alias.

```
functions -e [alias name]
```