# Removing ghostscript alias

Tags: command-line, bash, alias

I'm using `zsh` which uses `gs` as an alias for `git status`. But on Ubuntu, `gs` is an alias for ghostscript. I tried uninstalling ghostscript, but then I get this instead:

```
The program 'gs' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt install ghostscript
zsh: command not found: gs
```

I've also tried:

```
unalias gs
```

As explained here:

[How to remove an alias?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/325368/how-to-remove-an-alias)

But that gives me `unalias: no such hash table element: gs`.

How do I solve this?

Comment: AFAIK `gs` isn't an *alias for* ghostcript, it's a binary program *provided by* the `ghostscript` package

Comment: Ok, but how would I get rid of that and have it do what I want it to do?

Comment: I guess your real question should be *"why is zsh dropping to command-not-found for `gs` when I have defined an alias for it?"*

Comment: Are you sure zsh has this alias set up? Aliases are found before executables so the behavior you describe suggests that there is no such alias. Could you show us the relevant line from your `~/.zshrc` file? Does it work as expected if you run `alias gs="git status"` and then `gs`?

Comment: @terdon That was it, thanks. And in fact, for some reason the `git status` was mapped to `gst`. On mac it isn't. Please add as answer and I will accept

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It sounds like you simply don't have this alias defined. Aliases take precedence over hashed executables like `gs`, the presence of `gs` on your system wouldn't affect the alias at all. So, just add this line to your `~/.zshrc`:

```
alias gs='git status'
```

Save the file, open a new terminal and you should be all set.

Now, ghostscript is quite useful and you might want to reinstall it. If you do, you can run it as `\gs` or `command gs`.