# List or remove terminal aliases

Tags: command-line, alias

Say I have set up a few aliases for long bash commands:

```
alias test1='long-command-1'
alias test2='long-command-2'
```

and so on. Is it possible to list all aliases currently defined (ideally with the command it is an alias for)? Is it possible to undefine (remove) an alias?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/325368/how-to-remove-an-alias

Comment: Why on earth would anybody vote this question down (even assuming the other question is a partial duplicate)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To list all the aliases defined in the system, open a terminal and type `alias`.  It lists each `alias` and the command aliased to it.

As for removing an `alias` permanently, you can do this by opening your `.bashrc` file (in your home folder) with any text editor and and removing (or commenting out, by placing a `#` in front of them) the lines corresponding to the alias you want to remove. For the removal to take effect, you will need to close the terminal and open a new one or open a new bash shell by typing `bash`.

If, however, you want to remove the alias temporarily, you just do `unalias test1` and this will remove the alias for `test1`.  Remember, if you do it like this, alias `test1` will be there again the next time you open a terminal if it is defined inside your `.bashrc`.

Comment: To remove alias `test1`, use `unalias test1`.

Comment: @AlainD I have modified the answer to include this.