# bash: cd: too many arguments, help

Tags: bash, cd

I am trying to do cd test and get the error bash: cd: too many arguments.
I saw other threads saying that doing cd "test" would work but I get the same error message.

Also when I try to do cat test it give me ../../10/wsl

Any help would be greatly appreciated !

Thank you :)

Comment: What does `type -a cd` report? Is it an alias or something?

Comment: @Terrance, I tried typing cd ../../10/wsl but it still give me the same error message. @muru, it give me: cd is aliased to `cd -P tunnel' cd is a shell builtin.

Comment: @muru Good call!  I was off on that one.  =)  Looks like OP needs to remove the alias on cd.

Comment: @Terrance, how would I do this ? According to my assignment I could only use the commands ls, ln, cat and cd. Thank you for you help !

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/325368/how-do-i-remove-an-alias

Comment: Unfortunately I still get the same error message :(

Comment: You need to make sure that your `~/.bashrc` doesn't have that cd alias in it as well.  You can use your favorite editor like `gedit` and run from a command line `gedit ~/.bashrc` and look for if it is setting the alias.  Do not delete any lines other than just the `alias cd='cd -P tunnel'` line if that exists or a line similar to that one.

Answer (score 0):

too many arguments because:
when you type cd /mnt/c/user/e xample
there is gap between the letters. you have
to either

1. close it like this cd "/mnt/c/users/e xample"
   or
2. cd /mnt/c/users/e\ amples

hope it would help.